Drop metrics by value in Prometheus
Background:

I recently began using Istio + Envoy.
Envoy produces a bunch of metrics that are useful indicators of a specific error condition, but are 0 99.999% of the time (for example .*error metrics).

Note: At least in my view, this is not good metrics design (using labels or having a consolidated error counter that prompts the user to look at logs would be a better solution). But because this is a component of Envoy, this isn't something we have control over. Therefore, "just fix the metrics at the source" isn't a useful answer.



Question:

To reduce timeseries cardinality, I want to convert these to sparse timeseries (that is, only store them if they have a non-zero value).
Is there a way to configure Prometheus to drop any zero-valued metrics during collection?

